# How to update UI after providing a file download from JSF backing bean

Tags: jsf

I am able to provide a file download and show a loading animation, but I cant hide the loading animation after. I think its because of the `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();` that prevents the ui to rerender.
Any Ideas how to solve this problem.
Code below:

```
public String downloadStatistics(String serviceId) {
        ServiceTotal serviceTotal = getStat(serviceId);
        String tmpFolderPath = configuration.getWorkspace() + File.separator + TemporaryFolderNames.STATISTICS.getValue();
        try {
            if (serviceTotal != null && FileUtilFactory.getInstance().createPath(tmpFolderPath)) {
                File tmpFolder = new File(tmpFolderPath);
                File pdf = createStatisticPdf.createReportingPdf(tmpFolder, serviceTotal.getDocuments(), false);
                facesUtils.runJavaScriptMethod(HIDE_LOADING_ANIMATION_METHOD);
                jsfDownloader.downloadFile(pdf);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showErrorMessage("Could not download statistics", e);
        }
        return VIEW_NAME;
    }
```

```
public void downloadFile(File file) throws IOException {
        FileUtilFactory.getInstance().readFileIntoOutputStream(getOutputStream(file), file);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    }
```

```
<h:commandLink id="link_stats2" action="#{statisticsViewModel.downloadStatistics(statisticsViewModel.currentStat.id)}"
                                       onclick="showLoadingAnimation('loading-animation-download')" styleClass="btn btn-default"> Download
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <img id="loading-animation-download" src="images/anim.gif" style="display:none" alt="waiting indicator"/>
```

I tried to hide before I call the `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();`
I tried to return the View as String
I tested which line is the problem. What intresting is, is that both lines in downloadFile method
prevent the hiding even if I comment out the other line.

Comment: jsf Phase events are one piece , but what is it response , session or custom scope? show the whole bean code. I know what a loading animation is but i cannot say it would be part of jsf except as a graphic image, that would be programmer controled e.g. hide a div visibility:hidden; css. Application/pdf mime type for download, i would send that by servlet not a page or it would simply be part of the actual server files list in its configuration of handled mime types if you want it to load to browser if the user has a configured reader compatible with the browser.

Comment: I added the .xhtml

What else do you need me to provide?

Comment: Your JSF bean , is it request scope or session scope?  note:  <img id="loading-animation-download" src="images/anim.gif" style="display:none" alt="waiting indicator"/> should be a JSF element (one of my img)  <h:graphicImage id="sldshimg" alt="slideshow app servlet context object stored" value="#{slideshowBean.base64stringfirstload}" rendered="true" style="width:1024px;height:768px;" />  NOTE the rendered= attribute , you are using a non jsf image element

Comment: Its session scoped. But the problem is the same even with a jsf element or not ?

Comment: are you trying to that ON the client or on the server processing? If it is the client, then you need to use a component event triggered by the user to request back to the server to re render the page.